Flat connection in trivial principal bundle is unique
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $P = M\times G$ be the trivial principal $G$-bundle over $M$. Define the canonical flat connection $\mathcal{H}_{flat} := TM \times G$.
Now let $\mathcal{H}$ be an arbitrary flat connection in $P$, i.e. every $x \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U \subseteq M$ such that $(P|_U, \mathcal{H}|_U) \cong (U\times G, \mathcal{H}_{flat})$.
The question is how to show, that $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_{flat}$, i.e. there is only one flat connection on $P = M \times G$, namely the canonical one?
It could be done in the following (non elegant) way:
Simply show that
$$\mathcal{H}_{(x,g)} = T_x M \times \{0_g\}$$
for all $(x,g) \in M\times G$. So, let $(x,g) \in M \times G$ and $U$ simply connected and open and paracompact with $x \in U$. Then the holonomy group of $(U \times G, \mathcal{H}|_U)$ in $(x,g)$ is trivial and there is a reduction to the holonomy bundle through $(x,g)$ which is given by
$$U \times \{g\}$$
(which is a principal $1$-bundle). But $U \times \{g\}$ has a unique connection given by $T(U\times\{g\})$. Therefore, since $\mathcal{H}|_U$ and $\mathcal{H}_{flat}$ are extensions of $T(U\times\{g\})$, by uniqueness of extensions it must be $\mathcal{H}|_U = \mathcal{H}_{flat}$. In particular,
$$\mathcal{H}_{(x,g)} = (\mathcal{H}|_U)_{(x,g)} = (\mathcal{H}_{flat})_{(x,g)} = T_x M \times \{0_g\}.$$
Is there a more or most elegant other way to show this fact? Is there maybe a simple argument why the connection form of $\mathcal{H}$ has to be $\pi_G ^* \theta$, where $\theta \in \Omega^1(G,\mathfrak{g})$ is the Maurer-Cartan form and $\pi_G : M\times G \to G$ is the natural projection?
EDIT: It seems that this "fact" is not a fact and is in fact not true in general (see answer of @Thomas below).
In this case:
where does my proof go wrong? Is there a full description or classification of all flat connections on $M \times G$?

In general, this is false. A flat connection yields a representation of the fundamental group of $M$ to the Lie group $G$ named the holonomy representation. For instance, if $G=\bf R$, any closed one form $\omega$ on $M$ defines a flat connection on $M\times R$, namely $\nabla = dt+\omega$, and two such connections, say $\nabla _\omega, \nabla _{\omega '}$ are equivalent iff $\omega, \omega '$ are co-homologus. More generaly two flat connections on the trivial bundle $M\times G$ are equivalent iff the two holonomies are conjugate.

The connection form is $\eta := dt + \pi_M^* \omega$, right? Why is the curvature of the connection zero? By closedness of $\omega$ it is $\Omega = d\eta + \frac{1}{2}[\eta,\eta] = \frac{1}{2}[dt + \pi_M^* \omega, dt + \pi_M^* \omega] = \frac{1}{2}([dt,dt] + 2[\pi_M^* \omega, dt] + \pi_M^[\omega,\omega]) = [\pi_M^ \omega, dt] + \frac{1}{2}\pi_M^[\omega,\omega]$. Why is $[\pi_M^ \omega, dt] + \frac{1}{2}\pi_M^*[\omega,\omega] = 0$? Further, where does then my proof of this "fact" go wrong?

Flat connections are classified by the space of homomorphism form the fundamental group to the Lie group $G$ up to conjugation. A good book is "connections, curvature and cohomology", by Greub Halperin Vanstone, or the classical Kobayashi-Nomizu.

My "proof" of this "fact" goes wrong at the place

the holonomy bundle through $(x,g)$ which is given by
$$U \times \{g\}$$ (which is a principal $1$-bundle).

This is not correct because it is only isomorphic but not equal to it!
Thus $\mathcal{H}_{(x,g)} \neq T_x M \times \{0_g\}$ in general.
What still holds is that if $M$ is simply connected then $(M\times G, \mathcal{H})$ is isomorphic to $(M \times G, \mathcal{H}_{flat})$ (take $U = M$ in the above proof)
but not equal to it in general.
If $M$ is not simply connected then the holonomy of $(M\times G, \mathcal{H})$ does not have to be trivial.
For example take $M = S^1$ and $G = \mathbb{R}$. Then $G= \mathbb{R}$ is a non trivial $\mathbb{Z}$-space by the canonical inclusion $\pi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\beta: M\times G = S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\times_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ with $\beta(e^{2\pi it},y) := [t,y-t]$ is an isomorphism of principal $\mathbb{R}$-bundles over $S^1$.
There is a flat connection $\mathcal{H}$ on $\mathbb{R}\times_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ such that the
bundle morphism $q: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\times_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \to [x,y]$ induces the canonical flat connection $\mathcal{H}_{flat}$ on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. So, there is the flat connection $\beta^*\mathcal{H}$ on $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. It has holonomy group $\mathbb{Z}$ which is not trivial.
